# Make typescript compile/lint from the other modules/packages in monorepo

Tags: typescript, react-native, tsconfig, monorepo

I am new to using monorepo with Typescript which has a *react-native* project and a *common* folder which contains the common files to be shared across projects and it is configured and works fine when the app is running.

I am facing problem with Typescript which shows error in the *common* files import statements where `react-native` components are imported and used. It says `Cannot find module 'react-native' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)`. So is there a way to make Typescript to look for the import into the *react-native* project (Mobile directory) `node_modules`?

**Monorepo structure:**

```
monorepo
    |
    |---Common
    |
    |---Mobile
```

**Common's tsconfig.json**

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "react-native",
    "lib": [
        "es2021"
    ],
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noEmit": false,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "esnext",
    "rootDir": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "composite": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationMap": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
},
}
```

**Mobile's tsconfig.json**

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "react-native",
    "lib": [
        "es2021"
    ],
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noEmit": false,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "esnext",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
        "*": ["*", "../Common/*"]
    },
    "composite": true,
    "rootDir": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationMap": true,
},
"references": [{ "path": "../Common" }],
"exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "babel.config.js",
    "metro.config.js",
    "jest.config.js"
]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with your `package.json`, not the `tsconfig.json`. You're looking for [peerDependencies](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/configuring-npm/package-json#peerdependencies). In short, this is used for libraries to say, "any application depending on this library should also depend on `XYZ`, so use the version of `XYZ` in the application".

In your `package.json` for `Common`, you'll have something like:

```json
"peerDependencies": {
  "react-native": "^0.68.2"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "react-native": "^0.68.2"
}
```

Note that you also want it in `devDependencies` because, while developing and running unit tests, there is no other application that imports the dependency.

---

Sidenote: in a monorepo, it's fine for them all to use the same version, as you'll probably update them all at the same time. If you were developing a library that's standalone, you typically want to use the **lowest** compatible version in `peerDependencies`. It makes the library easier to use for consuming applications. I'm not up to date on `react-native`'s versions, but e.g. if you made a library for normal React that uses hooks (which were introduced in 16.8), you might have:

```json
"peerDependencies": {
  "react": "^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0"
},
"devDependencies: {
  "react": "^17.0.2",
```

Comment: But I think this will install a separate node_modules into Common folder right? If it is so, I didn't want to duplicate the modules and maintain the versions separately which is why I wanted it to take it from the existing node_modules present in the Mobile folder.

Comment: Also if I run the app, it works fine without any errors or crashes. Typescript error is the problem.

Comment: If you are using `workspaces` with your package manager (and you really should), then it will hoist the copies to the root of the monorepo. If not, there will be duplicates.
It's not clear how you're running it if it doesn't compile...
I forgot to mention, did you also `npm i -D @types/react-native`? The typescript error states that it could be either the module itself or its types.
Either way, that the error is emitted by typescript is a red herring. `"moduleResolution": "node"` means that TS simply asks node to resolve all modules. TypeScript doesn't "look for the import" at all.

Comment: Regardless, each project/library that has a `package.json` should directly reference all of its dependencies in that `package.json`. Always. That's the entire purpose of having independent packages; they're completely self contained. Getting something to work without that is a hack, not a fix. Technically, you could just globally install all of the dependencies of all all of your projects. It'll work on your machine, but nowhere else.

Comment: Ok. Got it. So my project runs successfully because I have made some updates to metro.config.js so that the Mobile project includes the Common folder while running the app. Refered this for updating metro.config.js -> https://dushyant37.medium.com/how-to-import-files-from-outside-of-root-directory-with-react-native-metro-bundler-18207a348427 Also I have installed @types/react-native and other @types too.